# What is the opposite of string.next?

Tags: ruby, string

Is there a method in Ruby that does the opposite `String#succ`?

If you run `succ` or `next` you get this:

```
a = "4.4.10"
a.succ
=> "4.4.11"
```

I want the opposite:

```
a = "4.4.10"
a.previous
=> "4.4.09"
```

Is this possible? I was having a hard time finding this in the Ruby docs. Maybe it doesn't exist?

Comment: I don't know about one too. But it shouldn't be too hard to implement your own.

Comment: I figured that was the case. Have any good suggestions on an approach to writing it?

Comment: Split on dots, pick the last segment, cast to int, decrement, assemble string back. It's, like, 3 lines of code :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, the real implementation is not that simple: `"sergio".next
=> "sergip"` `"sergio!".next => "sergip!"`, although what OP seems to want _is_ simple.

Comment: It's seriously not that easy, when going up you just increment, but you could have skipped versions like 3.2 -> 4.0 as in Rails. How do you handle that? How do you handle "4.4.00".previous? is it "3.3.99"? You sure?

Comment: @Dogbert: yes, if he only needs numbers, it's much simpler

Comment: @Baboon: yes, '3.3.99'. Do you have other logical options?

Comment: In case of rails, from 4.0 it would be 3.2.px

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`prev` or something similar is not in the standard API because `succ` and a hypoethetical `prev` are surjective. Despite this, "[Implement Ruby String Class Prev / Pred / Prev! / Pred! - Opposite Of Next / Succ Methods](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/implement-ruby-string-class)" is a possible version you could use.

The root problem is that `succ` is not inversible. This means, once you applied `succ`, then `prev` would end up with some ambiguity.

[image: surjective map of succ and prev]

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much. I'll have to give it a shot and see how it works!

Comment: I was just wondering about this, and this is an excellent explanation of why .prev would be very difficult to implement or predict if it were an actual method.

Comment: I'm actually a little confused by this explanation. Based on the diagram, it looks like `succ` is also ambiguous. Should maybe the second `succ` arrow not be there?

Comment: for ruby it's `.pred`

Comment: see https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-pred