# Is there an opposite of String.next?

Tags: ruby

What is the opposite of `next` in Ruby?
I am trying to find a function that is like `prev` which doesn't exist.

`"b".prev` would == `"a"`, just like `"a".next` == `"b"`

```
# A grad student at a local university thinks he has discovered a formula to
# predict what kind of grades a person will get. He says if you own less than 
# 10 books, you will get a "D". If you own 10 to 20 books, you will get a "C", 
# and if you own more than 20 books, you will get a "B".
# He further hypothesizes that if you actually read your books, then you will
# get a full letter grade higher in every case.
#
# grade(4,  false)  # => "D"
# grade(4,  true)   # => "C"
# grade(15, true)   # => "B"
```

Comment: There is nothing like that and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716522/opposite-of-string-next-in-ruby) is why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your case is limited to unique character the following will allow you to get the previous
or next character:

```
def next_char(c)
  (c.chr.ord + 1).chr
end

def prev_char(c)
  (c.chr.ord - 1). chr
end

puts next_char('A')
puts prev_char('B')
```

However, as you deal with grades, I'd go for a kind a Enumeration of grade. For instance, take a look at that [blog post](http://gistflow.com/posts/682-ruby-enums-approaches) for possible implementation.

Ref:

- [String.chr](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/String/chr)
- [String.ord](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/String/ord)
- [Integer.chr](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Integer/chr)