# why .downto method is not working?

Tags: ruby

Please see code as below:

```
"S".upto("Z") {|word| puts word}
```

It shows correct result.

But when I used `.downto` method, there was no result.

```
"Z".downto("S") {|word| puts word}
```

WHY?

Comment: Reason why `String#downto` or `String#next` does not exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716522/what-is-the-opposite-of-string-next/16716619#16716619

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it doesn't work because `String` doesn't have an downto method.   It only has `upto`.

Comment: OK!!Thanks a lot. but still confused~ Why just .upto is working!

Answer (score 1):

There is no downto method on Strings in Ruby (even though there is such a method for numbers). (Check: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html)

To that you may ask, "Why not?" And to that I have no answer.

Answer (score 1):

there no `.downto` method for a `String` object but you can do:

```
('S'..'Z').to_a.reverse.each {|word| puts word}
```

OR

```
"S".upto("Z").to_a.reverse.each {|word| puts word}
```

to achieve the result you expected.

Answer (score 1):

ell, there's a good reason for this: there's no method with that name declared for the [String Class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html)! Remember to look for the documentation of classes/methods when you're not sure.

But there's a workaround, don't worry, just extend the class with your own method. My try would be:

```
class String
    def downto value
        v = value.upto self
        v.to_a.reverse.each 
    end
end

puts "S".upto("Z").collect {|x| x}
puts "Z".downto("S").collect {|x| x}
```

Would render

```
Upto : ["S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
Downto: ["Z", "Y", "X", "W", "V", "U", "T", "S"]
```