# next and previous for letters and symbols array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Because

```
"A".next => "B"
```

and

```
"#".next => "$"
```

How would I find the *previous* item? So that:

```
"$".previous => "#"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it for individual characters:

```
('B'.ord-1).chr # => 'A'
('$'.ord-1).chr # => '#'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only need it to work on single character strings, you could extend String:

```
class String
  def previous
    return (self.ord - 1).chr
  end
end
```

Then:

```
"$".previous # => "#"
```

I'm not a big ruby programmer, so I don't know how bad of a practice this is, but it does work if you need it.

Comment: Yes! Monkey patch in the standard classes is a bad practice. To avoid this issue, you can create a `refinement`. Take a look: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html

Answer (score 2):

From [What is the opposite of string.next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716522/what-is-the-opposite-of-string-next)

> `prev` or something similar is not in the standard API because `succ` and a hypoethetical `prev` are surjective. Despite this, "[Implement Ruby String Class Prev / Pred / Prev! / Pred! - Opposite Of Next / Succ Methods](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/implement-ruby-string-class)" is a possible version you could use.
>
> The root problem is that `succ` is not inversible. This means, once you applied `succ`, then `prev` would end up with some ambiguity.
>
> [image: surjective map of succ and prev]

Credits to [Bjoern Rennhak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2368241/bjoern-rennhak).