# Using String.succ with different rules?

Tags: ruby, string, generator

I currently need to code an id generator and I would like to get help on how I can do it.  Basically, the id has number and letter.  I wanted to use succ, but it doesn't quite do what I want.  Here is the order I would like to have:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, ... , 8, 9, "a", "b", "c", "d", ... , "x", "y", "z", "00", "01", "02", ..., "0a", ...]
```

Do you think it's possible to pass an array of what come next to succ ?  Basically I would just pass something like that.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

EDIT:
Basically I want to know the next id from an id.  For example, I have a34b and this would give me a34c or a329 would give me a32a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` you are trying to generate can be seen as a **base 36** number. So we can use [String#to_i](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i) and [Fixnum#to_s](http://apidock.com/ruby/Fixnum/to_s) methods' to convert base systems (between 2 and 36).

**Note**: I also added a `String#prev` method as it may make sense here; but [such a method isn't provided in the standard API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16716619/2602869).

**Warning**: Monkey patching core classes isn't a good practice; I just posted it as the question specifically mentioned `String#succ`; it may be better to subclass `String` to create a new `id` type.

**Credits**: Idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84485/2602869).

```
class String
  def succ
    (self.to_i(36) + 1).to_s(36)
  end

  def prev
    (self.to_i(36) - 1).to_s(36)
  end
end

'a329'.succ # => "a32a"
"a32a".prev # => "a329"
```

Comment: Thanks ! I now feel dumb to not have though about that ahaha :P

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you basically want the id to be in base 36 (which is the numbers 0-9 plus the letters a-z). To increment a string using base 36, you should do the following:

1. Translate the string into an integer: `nextid = last_id.to_i(36)`
2. Add one: `nextid += 1`
3. Convert back to a string: `nextid = nextid.to_s(36)`

Comment: I was thinkg about doing this, but I find it none efficient to generate all the possible id only to get the next one ?

Comment: If this doesn't fit your use case, maybe you should post some sort of details about how you plan to use these numbers. You can't just calculate it once, find the index in the array of the last used id, and then add one to that index?